# Counter example for this statement

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let a Markov Chain and ${A}_{0}, \, {A}_{1} \dots {A}_{n} $ subsets of state space where $A_n$ is not a singleton.  Giving an example, verify that the following statement is not correct

$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=j|X_{n} \in {A}_{n}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=j|X_{0} \in {A}_{0}, X_{1} \in {A}_{1}, \dots X_{n} \in {A}_{n})$

Comment: Why would this be incorrect? This is the very definition of a Markov chain.

Comment: Is part of one exercise of the book Adventure in Stochastic processes by Resnick. I know that the statement is true when $A_n$ is a singleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $j>1$ and $A_2=\{j-1,j+1\}$ and that the transition probabilty from $j-1$ to $j$ is $1$ and that the transition probability from $j+1$ to $j$ is $0$.

Assume, furthermore, that the chain starts at $0$ and transitions to $-(j-1)$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-(j+1)$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Assume that we then transition from $-(j+1)$ to $j+1$ with probability $1$ and transition from $-(j-1)$ to $j-1$ with probability $1$.

Then, letting $A_0=\{0\}$ and $A_1=\{j-1\},$ we now have
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_3=j|X_2\in A_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=-(j-1))=\frac{1}{2} \\
\mathbb{P}(X_3=j|X_0=0,X_1\in A_1,X_2\in A_2)=1,
$$
since the behaviour of $X_2$ is deterministic once we've fixed $X_1$.

So the intuitive short-cut is that the $A_j$ sets might hold non-trivial information about where in $A_n$ you're starting, and this affects the conditional probability. Of course, if $A_n$ is a singleton, there is no possible non-trivial information about our starting point and so, this intuition does not violate the definition of a Markov chain.

Comment: Of course, you should be able to provide a less pathological example by having $X_2|X_1$ be non-deterministic, but it seemed like more of a hassle to write down.