# $P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n, \ldots , X_{t_1} \in A_1]=P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n]$ but $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ not independent

Tags: probability, measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb N}$ be a stochastic process on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ with countable state space $S$.

Let $n \ge 1, t_1<t_2<\ldots <t_{n+1} \in \mathbb N$ and $A_1,\ldots,A_{n+1}\subseteq S$ such that  $P[X_{t_n} \in A_n, \ldots X_{t_1} \in A_1]>0$.

Consider

$$\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n, \ldots , X_{t_1} \in A_1]=\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n]$$

If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are independent, then this is true.

I'm looking for a counter-example to disprove the other direction, i.e.

$$\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n, \ldots , X_{t_1} \in A_1]=\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n]$$ but $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are not independent

Comment: Just a (first-order) Markov chain works, doesn’t it?

Comment: @Mindlack Markov chain would be $$\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} = i_{n+1}|X_{t_n} = i_n, \ldots , X_{t_1} = i_1]=\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} = i_{n+1}|X_{t_n} = i_n]$$ which is weaker than $\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n, \ldots , X_{t_1} \in A_1]=\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n]$

Comment: That’s the definition of a Markov chain. But the property you want does hold (if you’re not convinced, transform everything into products and decompose the $A_i$ into elementary events).

Comment: @Mindlack It need not. Check this counter-example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366444/counter-example-for-this-statement/3366563#3366563

Comment: @Mindlack We saw in lecture that the defintion (the line with the $i_{n}$) does not imply the property with the $A_n$, it is weaker.

Comment: I mean it's not too hard to come up with *some* counter-example. For instance, if $X_t=X_1$ for all $t$, then you only ever need to condition on one of the variables to know the behaviour of all the rest, but I'm assuming this isn't entirely satisfactory to you?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou You mean if $X_n=X_1$ for all $n$, then $\mathbb P[X_1 \in A_{n+1}|X_1 \in A_n, \ldots , X_1 \in A_1]=\mathbb P[X_1 \in A_{n+1}|X_1 \in A_n]$. Because the 'information' or condition $|X_1 \in A_n, \ldots , X_1 \in A_1$ is the same as $|X_1 \in A_n$ as all $X_n$ are equal?

Comment: I guess it's actually not quite true... unless one of the $A_j\subseteq A_{n+1}$ or one of the $A_j\subseteq A_{n+1}^c$.

Comment: It *is* definitely true that $\mathbb{E}(X_1|X_1)=X_1$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: That’s unexpected to me. Thank you for pointing my mistake.

Comment: By taking $t_i=i$, $A_n=S$, it seemingly follows that $X_{n+1}$ is independent from $X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1}$. That’s a remarkably strong property, I wonder if it’s enough to prove the $X_i$ to be independent.

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, I was wondering about that as well. At first I thought the professor meant markov property instead, but as we saw this is not markov property. Do you think the counter example of @.WoolierThanThou works?

Comment: @user711482: it can’t work as is, since $X_3$ and $X_1$ must be independent (so if all the $X_i$ are equal, they must be constant). I’m thinking of something more elaborate, for instance: take $U_n$ a sequence of independent random variables in $S$, functions $f_n:S \rightarrow S$, and take $X_{2n-1}=U_n$, $X_{2n}=f_n(U_n)$.